# Match strings from two files and output fields in specific order

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following two files.

query.txt

```
pumpkin
kiwi
```

subject.tsv

```
kiwifruit   something   green
melon   something   red
pumpkinhead something   orange
```

I'd like to loop through query.txt and check for each line if any first field in subject.tsv contains the line. If yes, a tab plus the third field from subject.tsv shall be added to the line. The order of the lines in query.txt shall be preserved in the output.

I tried the following.

```
while read query; do echo -e $query"\t"; awk '$1 ~ "$query" {print $3}' subject.tsv; done < query.txt
```

desired output:

```
pumpkin orange
kiwi    green
```

actual output:

```
pumpkin
kiwi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash does not perform variable expansion on a string disclosed in single quotes (`'`), so the problem with your script is here:

```
'$1 ~ "$query" {print $3}'
```

It must be something like this:

```
'$1 ~ '"$query"' {print $3}'
```

But, even after fixing that your script will still be inefficient and prone to errors. So I suggest you to do that in a single awk call like this:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
NR==FNR { a[$0] = $3; next } {
    for (b in a) {
        if (index(b, $0)) {
            print $0, a[b]
            break
        }
    }
}' subject.tsv query.txt
```

Comment: I'm quite inexperienced with awk and couldn't figure out how the script works. Would you explain it?

Comment: @Matthias Just read the awk manual. Explaining such a simple script would be a waste of time

Answer (score 1):

although there is a lot of information missing in the question, like if the query file contains unique strings? or the subject file contains repeated strings? but given the current files and the requirement, please have the answer below, and since it is awk based, it should work on large files as well:

```
awk ' BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
    FILENAME ~ /subject.tsv$/ {
      color[$1]=$3
    }
    FILENAME ~ /query.txt$/ {
      for (i in color) {
      if ( i ~ $1 ) print $1, color[i]
    }
 }'  subject.tsv query.txt
```

Below is the output:

```
    pumpkin orange
    kiwi    green
```

Comment: I have tried the solution from @oguzismail and it is only printing the values in query file, but not the corresponding value in third tab, as required by OP.

Comment: Both the solution from @oguzismail and this one work equally well for me. I upvoted both and accepted the first one.

Answer (score 0):

In your version of codes using `while`, you need to pass the string you want to search for to `awk` command using `-v` option, otherwise `awk` will treat all as plain strings.

For example, if you want to pass a string 'pumpkin' contained by a variable `query`, you need to do like this:

```sh
query="pumpkin"; awk -v query=$query '$1 ~ query' subject.tsv
```

`-v` here is used to declare a variable that uses the content of a variable outside `awk`. You can see the explanation of `awk`

> -v var=val
>   --assign var=val
>    
>   Assign the value val to the variable var,  before  execution  of the  program  begins. Such variable values are available to the BEGIN rule of an AWK program.

Therefore, you can try to revise your codes accordingly by passing your `query` to the `awk`.

Comment: This may work for this particular case but `field ~ variable` is generally a bad practice. What if OP's query contains a dot or a question mark?

Comment: @oguzismail Yes you are right. I didn't take special characters into consideration. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here a bash solution

```
while read pattern; do
    column1=$(cut -d " " -f1 subject.tsv | grep "$pattern")
    allcolumns=$(echo "$pattern $(grep $column1 subject.tsv)")
    echo $allcolumns | cut -d " " -f1,4
done < query.txt
```

**explanation**

Read all lines of query.txt

```
while read pattern; do
   ...
done < query.txt
```

Find searchpattern in column1

```
while read pattern; do
   column1=$(cut -d " " -f1 subject.tsv | grep "$pattern") 
   echo $column1
done < query.txt
```

output

```
pumpkinhead
kiwifruit
```

Merge pattern from query.txt with matches from subject.tsv

```
while read pattern; do
    column1=$(cut -d " " -f1 subject.tsv | grep "$pattern")
    allcolumns=$(echo "$pattern $(grep $column1 subject.tsv)")
    echo $allcolumns
done < query.txt
```

output

```
pumpkin pumpkinhead something orange
kiwi kiwifruit something green
```

Extract first an last field from merge

```
echo $allcolumns | cut -d " " -f1,4
```

output

```
pumpkin orange
kiwi green
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command line Perl

```
$ perl -lane ' BEGIN { open($fh,"query.txt");@q=<$fh>;chomp(@q) } @s=/(\S+)/g; 
    /$q[0]/ and print "$q[0] $s[2]"; if(eof) { close($ARGV); shift @q}; ' subject.tsv subject.tsv
```

with your inputs.

```
$ perl -lane ' BEGIN { open($fh,"query.txt");@q=<$fh>;chomp(@q) } @s=/(\S+)/g; 
     /$q[0]/ and print "$q[0] $s[2]"; if(eof) { close($ARGV); shift @q}; ' subject.tsv subject.tsv

pumpkin orange
kiwi green

$
```